# Use reg_query to return data only for Typed URL and SystemshutDown

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-7, registry

```
C:\Users\Admin1>REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Windows /v ShutdownTime
```

Retruns

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Windows
    ShutdownTime    REG_BINARY    42B96F5BC9F7D101**

I want CMD to show only the data of the key **42B96F5BC9F7D101** so that I can output this to a csv file

Ive googled and read the forum and obtained this from another example -

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Windows /v ShutdownTime 2^>nul') do set "ShutdownTime=%%b"
echo %ShutdownTime%
```

which returns

```
C:\Users\Admin1>for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001
Control\Windows /v ShutdownTime 2^>nul') do set "ShutdownTime=%%b"
%%a was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\Admin1>echo %ShutdownTime%
%ShutdownTime%
```

I also want to obtain only the data to display from

```
REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs /v url1
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

#### %%a was unexpected at this time.

That error is because `for` loop parameters are named with a single `%` when used in a `cmd` shell and with a double `%%` when used within a batch file:

> ```
> %%parameter :  A replaceable parameter:
>                in a batch file use %%G (on the command line %G)
> ```

Source [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

So you need to replace `%%a` with `%a` and `%%b` with `%b`.

Example 1:

```
F:\test>@for /f "tokens=2*" %a in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Windows /v ShutdownTime 2^>nul') do @set "ShutdownTime=%b"

F:\test>@echo %ShutdownTime%
BE7AE7FCE7DCD101
```

Example 2:

```
F:\test>@for /f "tokens=2*" %a in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs" /v url1 2^>nul') do @set "Url1=%b"

F:\test>@echo %Url1%
http://www.example.com
```

Note:

- Example 2 has quotes `"` around the key name as it contains spaces.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.